# I want the identity seed of my PK start from 1

Tags: sql, ssis, key, ssms, definition

I will try to be short and explicit.

When I importing data to my DW from SSIS, the Primary Key of Dimension tables are not starting from 1.  This is happening each time I run my SSIS - it deletes all the information from the tables and then reloads them.  But why is the Primary key continuously incrementing?

I changed the definitions on SSMS by selecting the following:

```
**(Is identity)** "YES"
**Identity Increment** 1
**Identity seed** 1
**Not for replication** "YES"
```

After this change, whenI run the SSIS just continues with the previous numeration.

Can someone help with this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to issue a `TRUNCATE TABLE` rather than `DELETE`.  Truncate will reinitialize your `IDENTITY` column